# Looping through a Python log file doesn't actually loop through the contents and gives me different entries

Tags: python, logging

So I'm trying to parse a log file right now and I'm a bit confused regarding how to do that.

I have a log file, say `log_file.log`, and the contents of that file are like this:

```
1 03/25/2020 16:41:18 - INFO - X -   Loading X with AVX2 support.
2 03/25/2020 16:41:18 - INFO - __main__ -   Query address: http://163.XXX.XXX.XXX:9011
3 03/25/2020 16:41:18 - INFO - __main__ -   Doc address: http://163.XXX.XXX.XXX:9020
4 03/25/2020 16:41:18 - INFO - __main__ -   Index address: http://163.XXX.XXX.XXX:80
5 03/25/2020 16:41:18 - INFO - mips_new -   using doc ranker functions: <bound method NaturalKB.get_doc_scores of <__main__.NaturalKB object at 0x7fdc3a95dac8>>
6 03/25/2020 16:41:18 - INFO - mips_new -   Reading dump/
7 ^Mloading idx2id:   0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]^Mloading idx2id: 100%|██████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 34.70it/s]
8 03/25/2020 16:41:20 - INFO - __main__ -   Starting Index server at http://163.XXX.XXX.XXX:80
9 03/25/2020 16:41:22 - INFO - mips_new -   1st rerank (1000 => 100), (1, 100), 0.4613668918609619
10 03/25/2020 16:41:23 - INFO - mips_new -   2nd rerank (100 => 10), (1, 10), 0.29343676567077637
11 03/25/2020 16:41:23 - INFO - tornado.access -   200 GET /search?query=%3F (163.XXX.XXX.XXX) 1080.74ms
12 03/25/2020 16:41:23 - INFO - tornado.access -   200 GET /files/js/jquery.min.js (163.XXX.XXX.XXX) 9.37ms
13 03/25/2020 16:41:23 - INFO - tornado.access -   200 GET /files/js/jquery.easing.min.js (163.152.20.191) 1.97ms
14 03/25/2020 16:41:23 - INFO - tornado.access -   200 GET /files/js/bootstrap.min.js (163.XXX.XXX.XXX) 1.95ms
```

When I do:

```
with open(file='log_file.log', mode='r') as f:
    log_file = f.readlines()

print(log_file[0])
print(log_file[1])
```

I get:

```
>>> 03/25/2020 16:41:18 - INFO - X -   Loading X with AVX2 support.
>>> 03/25/2020 16:41:18 - INFO - __main__ -   Query address: http://163.XXX.XXX.XXX:9011
```

However, when I try to loop through it like this:

```
for idx, line in enumerate(log_file):
    print(line)
    if idx == 5:
        break
```

I get:

```
03/25/2020 07:27:14 - INFO - X -   Loading X with AVX2 support.

03/25/2020 07:27:14 - INFO - __main__ -   Query address: http://163.XXX.XXX.XXX:9010

03/25/2020 07:27:24 - INFO - run_natkb -   load with different params =>

03/25/2020 07:27:24 - INFO - run_natkb -   Loaded weight does not have {'module.sparse_end_q.2.query.bias', 'module.sparse_start_q.2.key.bias', 'module.q_linear.bias', 'module.sparse_end_q.1.query.weight', 'module.sparse_end_q.1.key.bias', 'module.sparse_end_q.2.key.weight', 'module.sparse_start_q.1.query.bias', 'module.sparse_end_q.1.query.bias', 'module.sparse_end_q.1.key.weight', 'module.sparse_start_q.2.query.weight', 'module.sparse_start_q.2.key.weight', 'module.sparse_end_q.2.query.weight', 'module.sparse_start_q.1.query.weight', 'module.sparse_start_q.2.query.bias', 'module.q_linear.weight', 'module.sparse_start_q.1.key.weight', 'module.sparse_end_q.2.key.bias', 'module.sparse_start_q.1.key.bias'}

03/25/2020 07:27:24 - INFO - run_natkb -   Model code does not have: {'module.linear.bias', 'module.tfidf_weight', 'module.linear.weight', 'module.true_help'}

03/25/2020 07:27:24 - INFO - __main__ -   Model loaded from /home/user/models/model.pt
```

I'm assuming that this is some sort of API call that's being output during the loop. Is there anyway that I can stop this and just get the contents of the log file itself?

#### Edit

The code that I'm running (through an IPython shell) is (I added more lines to the output so that my issue is a little clearer):

```
In [1]: with open(file='./log_file.log', mode='r') as f:
   ...:     lines = f.readlines()
   ...:

In [2]: for idx, line in enumerate(lines):
   ...:     print(line)
   ...:     if idx == 20:
   ...:         break
03/25/2020 07:27:14 - INFO - X -   Loading X with AVX2 support.

03/25/2020 07:27:14 - INFO - __main__ -   Query address: http://163.XXX.XXX.XXX:9010

03/25/2020 07:27:24 - INFO - run_natkb -   load with different params =>

03/25/2020 07:27:24 - INFO - run_natkb -   Loaded weight does not have {'module.sparse_end_q.2.query.bias', 'module.sparse_start_q.2.key.bias', 'module.q_linear.bias', 'module.sparse_end_q.1.query.weight', 'module.sparse_end_q.1.key.bias', 'module.sparse_end_q.2.key.weight', 'module.sparse_start_q.1.query.bias', 'module.sparse_end_q.1.query.bias', 'module.sparse_end_q.1.key.weight', 'module.sparse_start_q.2.query.weight', 'module.sparse_start_q.2.key.weight', 'module.sparse_end_q.2.query.weight', 'module.sparse_start_q.1.query.weight', 'module.sparse_start_q.2.query.bias', 'module.q_linear.weight', 'module.sparse_start_q.1.key.weight', 'module.sparse_end_q.2.key.bias', 'module.sparse_start_q.1.key.bias'}

03/25/2020 07:27:24 - INFO - run_natkb -   Model code does not have: {'module.linear.bias', 'module.tfidf_weight', 'module.linear.weight', 'module.true_help'}

03/25/2020 07:27:24 - INFO - __main__ -   Model loaded from /home/user/models/model.pt

03/25/2020 07:27:24 - INFO - __main__ -   Number of model parameters: 343,540,739

03/25/2020 07:27:24 - INFO - __main__ -   Starting QueryEncoder server at http://163.XXX.XXX.XXX:9010



Converting questions:   0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]03/25/2020 07:30:09 - INFO - pre -   tokens: are there geographic variations in the rate of co ##vid - 19 spread ?



Converting questions: 100%|██████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 867.31it/s]

03/25/2020 07:30:09 - INFO - tornado.access -   200 POST /batch_api (163.XXX.XXX.XXX) 76.77ms



Converting questions:   0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]03/25/2020 07:30:33 - INFO - pre -   tokens: are there geographic variations in the mortality rate of co ##vid - 19 ?


Converting questions: 100%|██████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 688.72it/s]

03/25/2020 07:30:33 - INFO - tornado.access -   200 POST /batch_api (163.XXX.XXX.XXX) 60.82ms


Converting questions:   0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]03/25/2020 07:32:39 - INFO - pre -   tokens: are there geographic variations in the rate of co ##vid - 19 spread ?
```

The output lines saying `Converting questions` is not a part of the log file.

Comment: Post the actual code you're running. Right now there's not enough information to identify your issue.

Comment: This is the actual code that I'm running. I turned on an IPython shell and ran the loop above after reading in the log file. I'll edit it to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Are you bothering about new lines?  In case, just use `line.strip()`

Comment: As the timestamps are different it looks like your loop has read a different file.

Comment: Funny enough, I opened the original log files and saved them as a different name but with a `.txt` extension. Reading and outputting that file is fine, but the original log file seems to be giving me weird results.